# MySQL Error when Querying Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a simple query to the database. It is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `photoslam`.`users` 
( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`email` VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL , 
`full_name` INT(124) NOT NULL , 
`username` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL , 
`password` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL , 
`bio` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL , 
`phone_number` INT(11) NOT NULL , 
`gender` ENUM(0) NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) 
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

I am receiving this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = MyISAM' at line 1

All the answers to this error I found had to do with changing TYPE = MyISAM to TYPE = ENGINE, but mine is already correct here.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html *"An ENUM is a **string** object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values..."* - So, quote it `ENUM('0') NOT NULL`

Comment: You're welcome. There was a duplicate question about it.